# Laravel - Mailer Service?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm a bit of a noob with Laravel but I'm setting up a bug tracking system and have a question about how to remove multiple instances of sending mails. Let me show you how I've got it set up currently:

```
public function store(UsersRequest $request)
{
    $user = User::create($request->all());

    Mail::queue('emails.master', ['user' => $user], function($message) use ($user) {
    $message->to('someone@somewhere.com')
            ->subject('New User Created');
    });

    return redirect('/users');
}
```

So I have this method in a controller which creates a new user in my system, then I send the mail out. What I'd like to do is strip the mail call out to one line of code.

What's the best way to achieve this?

What I've found so far, is setting up a service to handle this - like this: http://lukefair.com/create-a-mailer-service-with-laravel-and-a-basic-working-example-of-dependency-injection/

This seems like a good idea to my noob brain and would achieve what I need it to. Is there a better way to do this than creating a service? Making use of events perhaps (although, I guess I'd still need a service for that)?

As I said, I'm a bit of a Laravel noob and haven't got these patterns and ways of doing things down yet.

Any advice would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical solution for problems like this is, in the Laravel world at least, to create a service provider. The article you linked is a good fit for what you are looking to do.

If you want to be able to access your new mailer class globally as you can with `Mail` and `Request` and any of the other familiar Laravel facades, you can [create your own](http://fideloper.com/create-facade-laravel-4) and it will be usable from anywhere in your application.